# Apache POI : xlsx not opening the file with MS Office excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I created a .xlsx file using XSSF workbook. I am able to read it properly via google docs but showing blank with MS excel 2007 ( that's the only excel I have) .

Any suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.xlsx` is a format introduced in Excel 2007. So it can be read by previous versions without proper plug-in installed (if there is one for your version)